# Ionic 3 "ionic cordova build android --prod" error Metadata version mismatch

Tags: angular, ionic3

After running command "ionic cordova build android --prod" getting following error.

```
Error: Metadata version mismatch for module C:/Users/newuser/Documents/project/project/node_modules/@ionic/storage/dist/src/storage.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3
    at StaticSymbolResolver.getModuleMetadata (C:\Users\newuser\Documents\project\project\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24474:34)
    at StaticSymbolResolver._createSymbolsOf (C:\Users\newuser\Documents\project\project\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24260:46)
    at StaticSymbolResolver.getSymbolsOf (C:\Users\newuser\Documents\project\project\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24241:14)
    at C:\Users\newuser\Documents\project\project\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23023:30
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at extractProgramSymbols (C:\Users\newuser\Documents\project\project\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23022:79)
    at AotCompiler.compileAll (C:\Users\newuser\Documents\project\project\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:22720:47)
    at CodeGenerator.codegen (C:\Users\newuser\Documents\project\project\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:30:14)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.codeGen (C:\Users\newuser\Documents\project\project\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:61:30)
    at Object.doCodegen (C:\Users\newuser\Documents\project\project\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\codegen.js:6:51)
```

**ionic info:**

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.14.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.14.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

System:

```
Node : v8.9.0
npm  : 5.5.1
OS   : Windows 10
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Comment: can you add your package.json?

Comment: Here is the package.json file www.transfernow.net/92j313b2omg5

123456

Comment: Hi @SurajRao any solutions for this.

Comment: not sure.. I suppose you tried clearing node_modules and running npm install or update your '@ionic/storage'?

Comment: Everything i have done with still getting same issue

Comment: I am facing the same issue and I updated to ionic 3.8.0 yesterday (ionic cli: 3.16.0, cordova: 7.1.0)

Answer (score 5):

As this [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/13323) states, it is due to a dependency of ionic storage 2.1.1 to angular 5.x. In my case running:

```
npm install --save @ionic/storage@2.0.1
```

restored my ionic storage to the 2.0.1 version and solved my problems.

Keep in mind that the package.json of your ionic storage could state that its version is 2.0.1 but if you see into the details you can find out that it is referencing a 2.1.1 package version.

Hope this could help you

Comment: I have remove ionic cordova and install and add npm install --save @ionic/storage@2.0.1 

it work fine now

Comment: Thanks! this helped!